# « Qui » peut-il devenir « qu' » à l'oral ?

Tags: oral, pronoms-relatifs, élision

J'ai entendu

> C'est lui qu'a dit ça.

Le locuteur a voulu dire (je crois)

> C'est lui qui a dit ça.

*Qui* ne donnant pas *qu'* devant une voyelle, c'est une faute. Faute grave pour un non natif. Dans le registre familier ce type de faute est-il acceptable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne vois pas comment une faute pourrait être grave pour un non natif et autrement pour un francophone natif.

En tout état de cause, *c'est lui qu'a dit ça* est simplement du français parlé familier pour *c'est lui qui a dit ça*. C'est souvent enfantin mais pas forcément.

L'élision du *i* est bien sûr considérée comme une faute à l'écrit, sauf si l'on rend un dialogue.